# How to access database in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

So I would like to make an user to admin in the app I have on heroku. When developing my app I can do it via `rails c` or I just open up the database file with some SQL viewer. But how can I do it for heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run the rails console in heroku, you have to use `heroku run rails console` (assuming you have the heroku toolbelt installed).

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3#console or https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#console